# Changing color of the active whole section in tab bar - iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitabbar

**(Hopefully) Quick question!**

I would like to make a custom tab bar design. Right now it looks like this: [image]

What I've done is:

- Changed the background color to dark grey
- Changed the tint color to blue.

But I would like to have the background of the active button be another color, like this:
[image]

So:

- Dark grey background
- White icons (Active as well as inactive)
- Background of selected button showing the state (blue in this case)

How can I accomplish this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be following these steps:

1. Set the background color for the whole tab bar:

   ```
   tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
   ```
2. Have your tab icon images be the color you want them to be (white). Then set up each tab like this:

   ```
   UIImage *tabImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image"];
   // make sure the original color of the image is used, rather than templating it
   tabImage = [tabImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
   myViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" image:tabImage  tag:0];
   ```
3. Set the `tintColor` of the tab bar to white also so that the selected tab won't change colors:

   ```
   tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   ```
4. Set the `selectionIndicatorImage` to get a blue background on the selected tab. You'll need to create an image either programmatically or by importing it.

Comment: I put step 2 in my viewDidLoad for the view controller on one of the tabs, but nothing changes... Where should i implement step 2 otherwise?